# how to chose the method to use based on variable type

Tags: java, parent-child

Here's my problem :
I have a class Piece that has method getName that return "P" (its just an example)
I have another class King that extends Piece and has redefined the getName method to return "K".

Now I have an array of Piece (Piece[] array)  (in this array there are object of instance King)
When I call the getName from all these object I always get "P" from all objects. 
I want to get "k" from King object and "P" from Piece object.
Here's an example :

```
Piece[] p = new Piece[1];
p[0] = new King();
p[0].getName() //I got "P" not "K"
```

How to resolve my problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Show us the code. It'll be much easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've not showed any code, I will show you a simple example:

```
public class Piece {

    public String getName() {
        return "P";
    }
}

public class King extends Piece {

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "K";
    }
}

public class JavaTest {

    public static void showNames(Piece[] p) {
       for (Piece x : p) {
          System.out.println(x.getName());
       }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Piece[] p = new Piece[]{
            new Piece(),
            new King()
        };

        showNames(p);
    }
}
```

Output

```
P
K
```

Comment: Thanks I forgot @Override. Now I know why we use it

Comment: @rabahRachid You never state if you will be storing `Piece` variables in `Piece[]` or only `King`. I assume the latter and hence my answer is based on that. See my newer answer. =)

Comment: It was another problem I will make another question

Comment: look for the other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20167361/two-dimensional-array-of-string-issue

Answer (score 2):

What you may want to do is make `Piece` an abstract class.  Since it is a base class that probably won't be instantiated directly, you will have other classes that extend it which are concrete classes, i.e. - King, Queen, Pawn, Rook, Bishop, Knight, etc.

```
public abstract class Piece {

    ... // other code

    public abstract String getName();

    ... // other code
}

public class King extends Piece {

    ... // other code

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "K";
    }

    ... // other code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you absolutely certain that **`King extends Piece`**?

This is known as an **is-a** relationship.  A `King` is a `Piece`, so it makes sense for it to inherit from `Piece`.

```
public class Piece {
    public String getValue() {
        return "P";
    }
}

public class King extends Piece {
    public String getValue() {
        return "K";
    }
}
```

With this, when you instantiate a new `King`, `getValue()` will return `"K"`, as you expect.

Answer (score -2):

*Previous answer deleted*

I have rectified the mistake in my previous answer to come up with a solution. I added a new method to the subclass called `getSpecificName()` which accepts an `int`argument to decide which `getName()` is to be called and thus gives you the proper value.

The code is available here: http://ideone.com/ioF06I

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class IdeoneBase{

    public String getName(){
        return "P";
    }   
}

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone extends IdeoneBase
{
    @Override
    public  String getName(){
        return "K"; 
    }

    String getSpecificName(int x){
        if(x == 1){
            return super.getName();
        }
        return getName();
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        IdeoneBase piece  = new Ideone();
        if(piece instanceof Ideone){
            Ideone p = (Ideone) piece; // without this downward cast, you cannot call getSpecificName(). You can only call that is common between the two.
            System.out.println(p.getSpecificName(1));
            System.out.println(p.getSpecificName(999));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If the method is overridden, then the overriding class' method is called, not the parent's method.  I just tested this out.

Comment: Yes, cast the `Piece` down to `King` and then call the method. I know my example is dumb but I used that for the sake of ease. Use some sort of check like `piece[0] instanceof King{ ... }`

Comment: @Makoto Hmm.. my answer is what I recall reading from a book. Let me check it , too =)

Comment: You don't need to statically cast the `Dog` variable to run the `Dog`'s `makeSound()`.  Runtime polymorphism will call the `Dog` version of `makeSound` whether the object is statically a `Dog` or an `Animal`.

Comment: I don't see how this answer applies.  The OP is calling a method that exists on the parent.  Clearly it does because it compiles.

Comment: @Makoto have a look at the newer answer.

Comment: Technically you're correct, but you're still doing way too much.  The overridden method is all you need.  I don't see the value or necessity of your second method.

Comment: OP wants a P or a K using a King instance. Hence that bridge method.